# MQTT with NGINX and Let's Encrypt

Tags: docker, portainer

I want to set up an MQTT (broker) server with NGINX and Let's Encrypt.

For information, I use this repository for NGINX and Let's Encrypt:
https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

Here is the diagram :

[image]

I already have several sites in place. (wordpress, portainer, ...)

This is my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mosquitto:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_MQTT_WEB}
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "1883:1883"
       - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./data-mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./data-mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./data-mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    environment:
      - DOMAIN= ${DOMAINS}
      - VIRTUAL_HOST= ${DOMAINS}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST= ${DOMAINS}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL= ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: ${NETWORK}
```

This is my environement file (.env) :

```
# Creation TOF
# Contact : My  EMAIL
#
# Containers name
CONTAINER_MQTT_WEB=MQTT_web-ssl

# Host
DOMAINS=mqtt.mywebsite.com
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@mywebsite.com
#
# Network name
#
# Your container app must use a network conencted to your webproxy
# https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
#
NETWORK=webproxy
```

I've an error, but i don't understand...

```
Creating MQTT_web-ssl ... error

ERROR: for MQTT_web-ssl  Cannot start service mosquitto: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/home/theking/Docker/docker-mosquitto-nginx-letsencrypt/data-mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf" to rootfs at "/home/.../dockerdrive/overlay/ee4ef10d2f021c03b1556d9547f8c877d83c9128cad37c2a2a4ba1ff2c367d40/merged/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Thank you for your help :)

Have nice day

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

For the docker-compose.yml is ok :

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  mosquitto:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_MQTT_WEB}
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
       - "1883:1883"
       - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/logs:/mosquitto/logs
      - ./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config:ro
    environment:
      - DOMAIN= ${DOMAINS}
      - VIRTUAL_HOST= ${DOMAINS}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST= ${DOMAINS}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL= ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}

networks:
    default:
       external:
         name: ${NETWORK}
```

But now ihave a error

> MQTT_web-ssl | 1615542527: Error: Address not available

This is my repository :
https://github.com/Tofdu31/docker-mosquitto-nginx-letsencrypt